# spring hibernate and caching using ehcache

Tags: spring, hibernate, ehcache

I am using spring 3.2 and hibernate 4.2.8  and tried using ehcache but the moment I annotate an entity class with @Cache(org.hibernate.annotations.Cache) i get the following exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given, please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory class name to property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class (and make sure the second level cache provider, hibernate-infinispan, for example, is available in the classpath).
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory.buildEntityRegion(NoCachingRegionFactory.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1797)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1868)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:247)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
    ... 42 more
```

My Configuration  is as shown below

```
<bean id="sessionFactoryAdmin"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="adminDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.digilegal.services.ahc.model.user" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> -->
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration">/WEB-INF/ehcache-entity.xml</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I have tried all possible links on the internet but could not solve the problem

Here is  my /WEB-INF/ehcache-entity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ehcache>
    <cache name="com.digilegal.services.ahc.model.user.UserNotifications"
        maxElementsInMemory="500"
        eternal="false"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="69"
        timeToLiveSeconds="65" />


    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="15" eternal="false" timeToLiveSeconds="60"
        overflowToDisk="true" />
</ehcache>
```

Thanks
​Nirav

Comment: Could you share your /WEB-INF/ehcache-entity.xml. It could be incorrect or you have missed that

Comment: Also verify whether you have the ehcache library on your classpath. Using maven <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>. The exception is thrown in situations when the ehcache lib is not on the classpath.

Comment: Well I think /WEB-INF/ehcache-entity.xml is in the classpath . Since when I did not mention /WEB-INF it gave me an error

Comment: The ehcache lib should be in the path. If you are using maven put this into the pom.xml <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: I am using following maven dependency for ehcache<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: @shippi any clue where am i going wrong ?

Comment: Nope. Just for fun try to change org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory to org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory.

Comment: is the ehcache-entity.xml correct?Tried changing the class to org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory but it did not work same error :(

Comment: The only difference with my config is that for config location i am using <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">ehcache.xml</property> as per http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/hibernate. Would give it a try also. ;) Therefore put  <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">

Comment: tried that as well but same result :(

Comment: No idea, sorry! Hopefully someone else would spot your issue. As a last suggestion i would really ensure that the ehcache lib is on your classpath. Right click project, choose properties after that Java Build Path/Libraries (tab), expand the maven dependencies and search for hibernate-ehcahe.

Comment: Thanks for the  help shippi , i verified hibernate-ehcache-4.3.4.Final.jar and ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar are both in my maven dependencies. Could it be cos of ehcache-core version?

Comment: I am using 4.3.0 but i don't think that this is the issue. Or i am sure that not

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this error recently, and in my case the error was in a test that was using a different session factory configuration to where no `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class` was specified.

So the presence of the `@Cache` annotation caused the test to abort with the exact same error.
In my case i did not want caching for that particular session factory so I added:

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
```

have a look at your config to see if you don't have multiple session factories defined, and some don't provide `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class`.

Comment: Thank you so much this did the trick, I had multiple session factory and had to disable hibernate second level cache in the other one .